# How do you display realtime jQuery.active in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I use `jQuery.active` to determine how long to wait in Selenium testing and am trying to figure out a way to get a "realtime" count of jQuery.active in the Chrome devtools.

I've run into a case where jquery is active for a bit longer than expected after clicking on one page, but I'm unsure if the slowness in testing is translating to the user experience.  I want to watch the jQuery.active count in the browser without selenium.

I do not have a background in javascript which is making it harder to even look up what I'm trying to do.

**Is there a way to get a near 'realtime' account of jQuery.active using Chrome's devtools?**

Comment: You could just use `setInterval` to dump the value every few miliseconds, if that is what you want: `setInterval(() => console.log(jQuery.active), 50)`

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work.  Now I have to figure out why the active count is so much higher while in selenium vs in browser.  If you put that in an official answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to dump the value every few miliseconds:

```
// dump every 50ms
setInterval(() => console.log(jQuery.active), 50);
```

Keep in mind this is debugging code, nothing you should ship to production :]

Comment: for posterity: when you use the commmand above in the devtools console, it returns an ID number.  This number can be used to `clearInterval(x)` afterward.